# Rotation applied centering its previous offset after dragging in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, rotation, drag

I want to make a view in swiftUI such that I can drag view as well as rotate the view based on its current offset. But unfortunately after translating the view, when I try to rotate, it rotates centering its base offset, not current center of the view. I am now looking for a precised solution such that the view will rotate from its current center.
My code is here for better understanding:

```
struct MyGestureView : View {
    
    @State private var lastOffset : CGSize = .zero
    @State private var offset : CGSize = .zero
    
    @State private var lastRotation : Angle = .zero
    @State private var rotation : Angle = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .offset(offset)
            .rotationEffect(rotation)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        offset.width = lastOffset.width + value.translation.width
                        offset.height = lastOffset.height + value.translation.height
                    })
                    .onEnded({ value in
                        lastOffset = offset
                    })
            )
            .gesture(
                RotationGesture(minimumAngleDelta: Angle.degrees(3))
                    .onChanged({ angle in
                        rotation = lastRotation + angle
                    })
                    .onEnded({ angle in
                        lastRotation = rotation
                    })
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotate the view *first*, without adding any offsets, so that the view is rotated correctly. Then you can add offsets, which does not affect the rotation.

i.e. switch the order of `rotationEffect` and `offset`:

```
.rotationEffect(rotation)
.offset(offset)
```

Comment: It works, nice. Thanks for your feedback with better explanation.